# Not able to process kafka json message with Flink siddhi library

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-flink, siddhi

I am trying to create a simple application where the app will consume Kafka message do some cql transform and publish to Kafka and below is the code:

JAVA: 1.8
Flink: 1.13
Scala: 2.11
flink-siddhi: 2.11-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT

I am using library: https://github.com/haoch/flink-siddhi

**input json to Kafka:**

```
{
   "awsS3":{
      "ResourceType":"aws.S3",
      "Details":{
         "Name":"crossplane-test",
         "CreationDate":"2020-08-17T11:28:05+00:00"
      },
      "AccessBlock":{
         "PublicAccessBlockConfiguration":{
            "BlockPublicAcls":true,
            "IgnorePublicAcls":true,
            "BlockPublicPolicy":true,
            "RestrictPublicBuckets":true
         }
      },
      "Location":{
         "LocationConstraint":"us-west-2"
      }
   }
}
```

**main class:**

```
public class S3SidhiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        internalStreamSiddhiApp.start();
        //kafkaStreamApp.start();
    }
}
```

**App class:**

```
package flinksidhi.app;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import flinksidhi.event.s3.source.S3EventSource;

import io.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.SiddhiCEP;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;

import static flinksidhi.app.connector.Consumers.createInputMessageConsumer;
import static flinksidhi.app.connector.Producer.*;

public class internalStreamSiddhiApp {

    private static final String inputTopic = "EVENT_STREAM_INPUT";
    private static final String outputTopic = "EVENT_STREAM_OUTPUT";
    private static final String consumerGroup = "EVENT_STREAM1";
    private static final String kafkaAddress = "localhost:9092";
    private static final String zkAddress = "localhost:2181";

    private static final String S3_CQL1 = "from inputStream select * insert into temp";
    private static final String S3_CQL = "from inputStream select json:toObject(awsS3) as obj insert into temp;" +
            "from temp select json:getString(obj,'$.awsS3.ResourceType') as affected_resource_type," +
            "json:getString(obj,'$.awsS3.Details.Name') as affected_resource_name," +
            "json:getString(obj,'$.awsS3.Encryption.ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration') as encryption," +
            "json:getString(obj,'$.awsS3.Encryption.ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration.Rules[0].ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault.SSEAlgorithm') as algorithm insert into temp2; " +
            "from temp2 select  affected_resource_name,affected_resource_type, " +
            "ifThenElse(encryption == ' ','Fail','Pass') as state," +
            "ifThenElse(encryption != ' ' and algorithm == 'aws:kms','None','Critical') as severity insert into outputStream";


    public static void start(){
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        //DataStream<String> inputS = env.addSource(new S3EventSource());

        //Flink kafka stream consumer
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> flinkKafkaConsumer =
                createInputMessageConsumer(inputTopic, kafkaAddress,zkAddress, consumerGroup);

        //Add Data stream source -- flink consumer
        DataStream<String> inputS = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);
        SiddhiCEP cep = SiddhiCEP.getSiddhiEnvironment(env);

        cep.registerExtension("json:toObject", io.siddhi.extension.execution.json.function.ToJSONObjectFunctionExtension.class);
        cep.registerExtension( "json:getString", io.siddhi.extension.execution.json.function.GetStringJSONFunctionExtension.class);
        cep.registerStream("inputStream", inputS, "awsS3");


        inputS.print();

        System.out.println(cep.getDataStreamSchemas());
        //json needs extension jars to present during runtime.
        DataStream<Map<String,Object>> output = cep
                .from("inputStream")
                .cql(S3_CQL1)
                .returnAsMap("temp");


        //Flink kafka stream Producer
        FlinkKafkaProducer<Map<String, Object>> flinkKafkaProducer =
                createMapProducer(env,outputTopic, kafkaAddress);

        //Add Data stream sink -- flink producer
        output.addSink(flinkKafkaProducer);
        output.print();


        try {
            env.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Consumer class:**

```
package flinksidhi.app.connector;


import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Properties;
public class Consumers {
    public static FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> createInputMessageConsumer(String topic, String kafkaAddress, String zookeeprAddr, String kafkaGroup ) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", zookeeprAddr);
        properties.setProperty("group.id",kafkaGroup);
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(
                topic,new SimpleStringSchema(),properties);
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

**Producer class:**

```
package flinksidhi.app.connector;

import flinksidhi.app.util.ConvertJavaMapToJson;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedSerializationSchema;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;

public class Producer {

    public static FlinkKafkaProducer<Tuple2> createStringProducer(StreamExecutionEnvironment env, String topic, String kafkaAddress) {

        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<Tuple2>(kafkaAddress, topic, new AverageSerializer());
    }

    public static FlinkKafkaProducer<Map<String,Object>> createMapProducer(StreamExecutionEnvironment env, String topic, String kafkaAddress) {

        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<Map<String,Object>>(kafkaAddress, topic, new SerializationSchema<Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void open(InitializationContext context) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public byte[] serialize(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
                String json = ConvertJavaMapToJson.convert(stringObjectMap);
                return json.getBytes();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried many things but the code where the CQL is invoked is never called and doesn't even give any error not sure where is it going wrong.

The same thing if I do creating an internal stream source and use the same input json to return as string it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial guess: if you are using event time, are you sure you have defined watermarks correctly? As stated in the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/libs/cep/):

> (...) an incoming element is initially put in a buffer where elements are sorted in ascending order based on their timestamp, and when a watermark arrives, all the elements in this buffer with timestamps smaller than that of the watermark are processed (...)

If this doesn't help, I would suggest to decompose/simplify the job to a bare minimum, for example just a source operator and some naive sink printing/logging elements. And if that works, start adding back operators one by one. You could also start by simplifying your CEP pattern as much as possible.

Comment: yes I have tried very simple jobs and it works with Kafka Consumer and producer perfectly , even this example worked , if I only stop the datastream from kafka and use the one at the top which is an internal datasource . But the moment I switch to kafka as the input datasource , the CEP stops being processed.

Comment: I am not sure how do we identify that its using event time and watermark , I am new to this ...

Comment: In the App class above , if we comment the kafka data stream and uncomment and use below as input source it works perfectly:
DataStream<String> inputS = env.addSource(new S3EventSource());

Comment: Based on watermark which I though may be an issue I added below for the Kafka Consumer: 
flinkKafkaConsumer.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy
                .forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20)));

but still it didn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks a lot @Piotr Nowojski , just because of your small pointer which no matter how many times I pondered over about event time , it did not came in my mind. So yes while debugging the two cases:

1. With internal datasource , where it was processing successfully, while debugging the flow , I identified that it was processing a watermark after it was processing the data, but it did not catch me that it was somehow managing the event time of the data implicitly.
2. With kafka as a datasource , while I was debugging I could very clearly see that it was not processing any watermark in the flow, but it did not occur to me that , it is happening because of the event time and watermark not handled properly.

Just adding a single line of code in the application code which I understood from below Flink code snippet:

```
@deprecated In Flink 1.12 the default stream time characteristic has been changed to {@link
     *     TimeCharacteristic#EventTime}, thus you don't need to call this method for enabling
     *     event-time support anymore. Explicitly using processing-time windows and timers works in
     *     event-time mode. If you need to disable watermarks, please use {@link
     *     ExecutionConfig#setAutoWatermarkInterval(long)}. If you are using {@link
     *     TimeCharacteristic#IngestionTime}, please manually set an appropriate {@link
     *     WatermarkStrategy}. If you are using generic "time window" operations (for example {@link
     *     org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream#timeWindow(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time)}
     *     that change behaviour based on the time characteristic, please use equivalent operations
     *     that explicitly specify processing time or event time.
     */
```

I got to know that by default flink considers event time and for that watermark needs to be handled properly which I didn't so I added below link for setting the time characteristics of the flink execution environment:

env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);

and kaboom ... it started working , while this is deprecated and needs some other configuration, but thanks a lot , it was a great pointer and helped me a lot and I solved the issue..

Thanks again @Piotr Nowojski